# Why does it need to use "of " in "I told her of my secret plans."?

Tags: prepositions

> I told her **of** my secret plans.

Why should it use "of" here?

How to parse this sentence?

Why not rephrase this sentence to "I told her my secret plans"?

Comment: If *I told her my plan*, that would normally mean I explained exactly what my plan was. Whereas if *I told her **of** my plan* (or the equivalent ***about***), that might mean I made her aware that I did actually *have* a plan, but didn't reveal any further details. But in practice this distinction doesn't always apply. Using ***of*** is slightly more formal/literary, and using ***about*** is slightly more colloquial, but all three versions are largely interchangeable and mean the same thing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @The Photon: There's more to it: *I told her my lies* would normally mean I *deceived* her with my lies, where *I told her **of** my lies* would mean I admitted to her that I'd been lying (but again, without *necessarily* telling her exactly what those lies were).

Comment: Can I say "I told my lies to her" ? Are they the same?

Answer (score 3):

> I told her my secret plans

This means you've told her the content of your secret plans.

> I told her { of | about } my secret plans

This could mean you've told her that you you have secret plans, but not the content of those plans.  As @FumbleFingers says though, the speaker could intend that the content of the plans was told as well.  Other conversation/text/context is needed to know for sure.  So you should not rephrase it unless you're sure of the speaker's/writer's intent.